# Apache httpd conf file 2.2

Tags: apache2

If I want to open an html file in the localhost - localhost/myfile.html, for example - do I need to change the httpd conf file of Apache? Actually I read in a book that this file name should be added at the line:

DirectoryIndex index.html

so it would be:

DirectoryIndex index.html myfile.html

I'm asking that because I've created an Google Map with some forms that use PHP and Ajax to GET data from users, but it is not working. So I thought that perhaps there's something wrong with Apache's configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Daniel Montenegro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not necesseray!

Actually the code wasn't working due to some problems on it. There was no relation to the httpd file configuration. Once I fix it, the file worked fine in localhost.

Thanks and please vote up!

Daniel